# how I could print in horizontal mode in chromium with command line in linux?

Tags: linux, printing, command, chromium

Im trying this command

```
   chromium-browser  --headless  --disable-gpu --print-to-pdf=file14.pdf file:///input.html
```

this command print verticallly

But i dont know how I could print in horizontal in command lines

Please hep me

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1281309/how-can-i-print-a-webpage-in-landscape-mode-using-headless-chromium-on-the-comma